# Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento1.9.2.3, format, datetime

Magento is saving datetime in a wrong format.
In form I'm using

```
$dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
$fieldset->addField('start_time', 'date', array(
        'name'   => 'start_time',
        'label'  => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Start Date'),
        'title'  => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Start Date'),
        'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
        'input_format' => $dateFormatIso,
        'format'       => $dateFormatIso,
        'time' => true
    ));
```

instead of "day month year" it saving it as "month day year" of course settings in Magento are correct. Why it is doing it ?
Can't find reason.
How can I change date format in form ?
I've changed 'input_format' and 'format' to Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
but now it gives me 2018-02-05 and can't select time instead but date/time saved is 05-02-2018 00:00 while I would like to have an option to change time as well or even set it for start date to 00:00:00 and for end date 23:59:59 to cover whole day.
How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT)`
instead of 
`Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);`

Comment: Thank you Chester, unfortunately it does not changed anything ;(
Whether it is Date or DateTime still changing format to "American" MonthDayYear which is driving me crazy.